# write the event bind the element's close-in parent

Tags: jquery

In my code history, I often write the jquery code,like this ,to write the event function on the near elements, yesterday, My friends told me that,you maybe write the event function on their near parents,like the code below:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
// write the event on a's parent 
$("#footer").on("click",function(e) {

})
// I often write like this
$("#footer a.first").click(function() {
   $('form').submit() 
})
//or write like this
$('#footer a').last().bind("click",function() {
    $('form')[0].reset()
})
})
```

I put the code the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Jackyhua/5Z9Lr/
Is anyone can tell some goods and examples to make me believe the true?

Comment: Could you clarify what your question is?

Comment: the way bind the event on their parent is better than bind self, this is my question!

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is

```
// write the event on a's parent 
$("#footer").on("click", 'a.first', function(e) {
    $('form').submit() 
})
$("#footer").on("click", 'a:last', function(e) {
    $('form')[0].reset()
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/auAKC/)

It uses event delegation to fire the handlers. It is mainly used when you have to register handlers for elements which are added dynamically. If the elements are added dynamically then the normal handler registration will not add the handlers to elements added after the event registration code is executed. In such a case, we added a delegated handler to a parent element which will present when the code is executing with a selector which filters the actual element that must trigger the event as the second parameter to `.on()` method.

In this particular case, it doesn't make much difference.

Comment: If under a block elments , there are events to occur, like 'click', may I can write them in one parent click, Can you give me some e.g?